# Is it possible to use RDP to connect to the server, without interacting with the GUI?

Tags: command-line, remote-desktop, windows-server

my first question in this community, so apologies for any formatting issues.

My Problem: I have many servers I need to be able to connect to via command line and run scripts. However, on those servers, all communication ports i.e. ssh, telnet etc are closed.

I have only port 3389 availible, that is used for the RDP. I know it is possible to log in to the server and get GUI using CLI, however, I need to be able to do this all in CLI, otherwise running scripts remotly will be really difficult.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:(cant respond, as no rep on the StackExchange and thought I might at least say what I have done, considering over 1000 people has seen this question)
In the end I have had to resort to create an elaborate bot that would mimick human behaviour while using GUI to acomplish tasks I needed.

Comment: "Remote Desktop..." implies a desktop environment, it's in the name. You should be using SSH indeed. Having it blocked but not RDP is weird, to say the least.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible this way. You will need to open more ports and add some firewall rules.

Comment: You should be able to disable the RDP service, and run the sshd service on port 3389. Not exactly correct, but perfectly doable.

Comment: are you using powershell? https://adamtheautomator.com/psremoting/